# ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received

Tags: python, text, vectorization, tf-idf, streamlit

I have this model and I tried to make a simple interface for it using streamlit. It follows the same transformation steps that were undertaken during the training phase so I don't understand what's wrong here. I supose it has to do with streamlit input and that I need to transform my input somehow, but I couldn't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

here is the code:

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pickle
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import joblib
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv('IMDB Dataset.csv')

train, test= train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
Xtrain, ytrain = train['review'], train['sentiment']
Xtest, ytest = test['review'], test['sentiment']

model = joblib.load('model.pkl')

st.title('Analisis Sentimen')

txt = st.text_input('masukkan teks yang ingin dianalisis')

tf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfdf = tf.fit_transform(Xtrain)
vect = pd.DataFrame(tf.transform(txt).toarray())
txt = pd.DataFrame(vect)
pred = model.predict(txt)
print(pred)
st.write(pred)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an `if` statement to `txt` before proceeding with the rest of the execution otherwise you will always encounter `ValueError` after this error is fixed. Now visit your `vect` variable, `transform()` is expecting `raw document`, meaning  an iterable input
which contains a single element. So you will have to convert the input which is a `str` by default into a list of string and after that, pass it to `transform()` as the parameter.

```py
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pickle
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import joblib
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('IMDB Dataset.csv')

train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
Xtrain, ytrain = train['review'], train['sentiment']
Xtest, ytest = test['review'], test['sentiment']

model = joblib.load('model.pkl')

st.title('Analisis Sentimen')
txt = st.text_input('masukkan teks yang ingin dianalisis')

tf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfdf = tf.fit_transform(Xtrain)

if txt is not None:
    raw_doc = [txt]
    vect = pd.DataFrame(tf.transform(raw_doc).toarray())
    txt = pd.DataFrame(vect)
    pred = model.predict(txt)

    print(pred)
    st.write(pred)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still returns the same error

Comment: I fixed the code, so you can try it again to see if it works.